# Python 2.7.10 64bit on Win10 - lib/test hangup

Tags: python, python-2.7

I am new to python. And I need to run getmail. After lots of error msgs I reduced my claim to run the tests under lib/test first:
`python .\test\regrtest.py -v -M 2.0Gb -uall,-bsddb,-largefile`

I am getting failure msgs from some of them but at:

```
test test_re failed -- Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "F:\python27_64\lib\test\test_support.py", line 1287, in wrapper
    return f(self, maxsize)
  File "F:\python27_64\lib\test\test_re.py", line 973, in test_large_search
    s = 'a' * size
OverflowError: cannot fit 'long' into an index-sized integer

Warning -- files was modified by test_sax
test test_shutil failed -- Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "F:\python27_64\lib\test\test_shutil.py", line 138, in test_rmtree_dont_delete_file
    handle, path = tempfile.mkstemp()
  File "F:\python27_64\lib\tempfile.py", line 314, in mkstemp
    return _mkstemp_inner(dir, prefix, suffix, flags)
  File "F:\python27_64\lib\tempfile.py", line 245, in _mkstemp_inner
    _set_cloexec(fd)
  File "F:\python27_64\lib\tempfile.py", line 50, in _set_cloexec
    flags = _fcntl.fcntl(fd, _fcntl.F_GETFD, 0)
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'F_GETFD'
```

python is hangup :-(

ALL ideas are welcome