# Python 2.7 - Windows 10 - pywin32 installation fails

Tags: python, windows, pywin32

For fixing my other problems I tried to install the `pywin32`.
As admin I used `pywin32-219.win-amd64-py2.7.exe`
the Path and everything is recognized for installation.

The installation stops with:

```
close failed in file object destructor: 
sys.excepthook is missing lost sys.stderr
```

I checked all registry entries, path, PYTHON_PATH an PYTHONPATH
and I installed `gcc-mingw-4.3.3`

BTW, I'm always local admin on this machine ;-)

Any ideas?

Comment: I don't know what > "For fixing my other problems"  means but have you tried Anaconda? It has a lot of stuff bundled, maybe you need it maybe not, but it is a quite stable distribution.

Comment: are you sure you have a 64 bits machine?

Comment: thx for your answer. YES I am sure to run a 64bit machine.
This ist my other problem. --- and I only wanted to run getmail :-)
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33844771/python-2-7-10-64bit-on-win10-lib-test-hangup

Comment: Did you try "pip install pypiwin32"?

Comment: yes, that's the one i am using now

Answer (score 0):

For Windows, there were two ways of getting win32 working with Python.

The non-cygwin way of using the [ActiveState Python distribution](http://www.activestate.com/activepython/downloads)  which happens to have the win32 included.

The cygwin way of installing python and installing the win32 module afterwards by compiling it (considerably more complex)

It seems that you are not following any of them, which is recipe for problems.

Comment: I installed ActiveState without problems in another directory. where should PYTHONPATH point to? to the old directory or the new one?